# How to understand obscure cookies from the developer dashboard?

Tags: cookies, encoding

I'm parsing the site, I see that the server sends me the link I need in response to a post request. There is no data in the post request, but there are cookies. The link is uniquely linked to the data entered on the site, therefore, from the fact that when entering the same data, cookies do not change from request to request, and when entering different data, they change, I conclude that the link I need is generated by these cookies. The data that is encoded and transmitted to cookies is known to me, but I do not understand how they are encoded, but I want to understand.

Here is the cookie fragment of interest:
`__cf_bm=r631oItrDAnoVB00vqbXjuw3b5vdHbms4wOoEmIWleI-1680297852-0-AV6s78StIN+ZUZAjy95UnnJZS8D0WiRM54bBa1vF7CqKN+IbFUPB4vxfnh1BFt6RsbzfPn24Ltkw5yyYLPECSu0=;`

I assumed that another tag would help decrypt cookies: `accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br`
But online converters cannot decode the above string with any of the encodings

Comment: See **sandro**'s answer at https://community.cloudflare.com/t/cf-bm-cookie/56696/3 It appears to consist of four values separated by dashes: - SHA1 hash; - Current time as Unix timestamp; - Some numeric value; - A base64 encoded value which appears to contain some binary data. (the datetime in Python: `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(xxx[1]))` returns `datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 31, 23, 24, 12)` in your case…

Comment: @JosefZ thank you very much! It's a pity that this is not the data I need.